# Search vs planning in artificial intelligence

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, search, planning

I'm studying artificial intelligence following the Russell & Norvig book. 
We did a search and planning part that for me is the same (at least on the representation).
I'd like to know what is the difference between these two techniques, but I couldn't find it.

Looking online I found this resource:
[Planning and Search](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psznza/G52PAS/lecture9.pdf), where it says: "The main difference between search and planning is the representation of
states."

Is the difference between these two techniques limited to the representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is "Yes".

Long answer is "No":

As far as I am concerned the difference is limited to a specific author/lecture:
(to the best of my understanding of the slides)
The author of the linked slides does not want to refer to "search" as a technique like planning, but rather as a general procedure.

Planning is the process of finding a set of (valid) actions that transform an initial state (set of properties) to a goal state. Such a problem can be represented by a state space graph, where each node defines a complete world state (i.e. a set of properties). Two nodes are connected if there exists a valid action transforming one state into another.

- "Search" is the general procedure of finding a solution by searching the problem space. In this case it is the process of iterating a state space graph starting at the initial node, trying to find a path to the goal node, i.e., using DFS. The search problem is given an (perhaps implicit) representation of the graph and is not concerned about internal properties of nodes.
- A non-search "Planning" algorithm on the other side may make use of the logical properties of the states to iterate the state space graph.

However, I would like to note that most "Planning" algorithms do use some kind of search procedure on the state space graph, significantly improving the search using planning-heuristics: 
Consider the graph given on slide 4 (of the referenced link). The complete graph represents the planning problem. The search "only sees" nodes and edges. A DFS would simply iterate all possible paths until a solution is found. A heuristic (planning algorithm) may use additional relations between properties (i.e. getting milk implies going to the supermarket first).

---

Informal definition of plan: the solution to a planning problem. A sequence of actions that translate the initial (world) state into the goal state.

In terms of the (graph) search this would be a list of edges to traverse. If there exists a valid plan, then there exists a path in the graph.

---

(this may be a little out of scope)
Since planning is in general PSPACE-complete naive search algorithms perform exceptionally bad on many instances. Common heuristics/techniques used in planning are based on the relaxation of the state space graph, i.e., by relaxing preconditions or effects (resulting in easier problems; in P, or NP) which can be solved "easily". If you are interested in planning that is somewhat separated from "search" you might wan to take a look at hierarchical task networks (HTN) which is basically planning with additional domain knowledge.

Comment: `If (strlen("yes")>strlen("no")) printf("Waaaait a minute!\n"); \\ ;-)`

Comment: to sum up I could say that a schedule is a sequence of actions that could lead to the goal, while in a search we have a series of actions, and one of this could be on goal?

Comment: I would not mix up terms here: a schedule relates to scheduling problems which is something completely different. 

To sum it up: In planning you try to find a "plan", which is a sequence of (applicable) actions leading to the goal. A (graph) search is a possible procedure to find such a plan.

Comment: So by definition, the plan has always a goal or goals? Instead, the graph search can be failed, right? @Fleeep

Comment: Added that to the answer. If graph search fails then there is no plan.